# I need a Text Box on Sharepoint site

Tags: inputformtextbox

I am using SharePoint 7 and I do not have any coding ability.  Is there a simple way to display a text box on my Sharepoint site?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to display a text box that can be easily accomplished by adding a Content Editor Web Part to the page and then adding the the text box html.  However, if you need to do something with data entered there, that will be more difficult.

```
<input type="text" name="mytextBox" value="hello world" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to add a textbox to your page, with varied amount of customisation required.  The best way will depend on what you want to *do* with the textbox.

For example, if you want to create an easy way for a user to go to an item, you can create a textbox and button in a content editor web part as Dave answered, then use javascript to construct the Url and send the user to the view page.

Alternatively, you can write a custom application page and deploy it, or write a custom web part to interact and connect with data.

Comment: I just want to post a text box as a read only.  I am a novice admin to our SharePoint site.  It appears that I do not have Content Editor Web Parts.  ??

Comment: What do you plan to do with the readonly text box?

Comment: Create a page, edit page, add a web part, you will see in the list a "Content Editor WebPart".  Click Edit Shared Webpart and click "Source".  Put the HTML in there.  Here is a link: http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2010/07/19/how-to-edit-source-in-sharepoint-2010-content-editor-web-part-cewp/

Comment: Is this only in Sharepoint 2010?  I have 7

Comment: SharePoint 2007 has a content editor web part too. Here's a link to the MS Office site with details on the web part: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/content-editor-web-part-HA010024046.aspx#BM2